# Creating a nice polynomial representation from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to translate `Polynomial({4:5,6:7,100:10})` in python to give me a clean output of the form of

```
[out]: 10*X^100 + 7*X^6 + 5*X^4
```

as a string.

So the first entry of the dictionary matches to the exponent of `X` and the second entry to its coefficient, always starting with the smallest exponent ascending to the highest. To get a feeling for the situation I tried to iterate over the dictionary and noticed that the output is not what I would expect

For instance if I setup the dictionary such as above `dictionary = {4:5,6:7,100:10}`
and I perform a print in the like of

```
for exponent in dictionary:
    print exponent
```

I get the output 100,4,6. Which is not very intuitive to me. However I looked into the `operator` module and some similar questions on this website and came up with the following piece of code.

```
import operator
```

`class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, polynom = {}):
        self.polynom = polynom
        self.poly_string = self.nicePolynom(polynom)`

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.poly_string

def nicePolynom(self, polynom):
    sorted_polynom = sorted(polynom.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    sorted_polynom.reverse()


    for element in sorted_polynom:
        exponent = str(element[0])
        coefficient = str(element[1])

        term = coefficient + "*X^" + exponent
        print term     
    return term
```

Which does basically what I want. However I am clueless on how to make it fit all together. My current output (induced by the rudimentary print statement in the code) is

```
10*X^100
7*X^6
5*X^4
```

and of course the return statement which just evaluates to 5*X^4. I do want the above output to be all in one line and have a " + " in between them just as in the output example above. However without writing very very ugly code (uglier than the one above) I can't complete this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what library you are using to get your Polynomial objects, but assuming it is a subclassed dict with all the normal methods and I've understood you, I believe you are trying to do this:

```
>>> d = {4:5, 6:7, 100:10}
>>> ' + '.join(('%s*x^%s' % (c, e) for e, c in d.items()))
'10*x^100 + 5*x^4 + 7*x^6'
```

Breaking that down a bit for you:

- `d.items()` returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples for the dict d.
- `'%s*x^%s' % (c, e)` formats the tuple: c*x^e [c=coefficient, e=exponent]
- `' + '.join(...)` puts it all together with plus signs in between.

Note that as always, dict order is not guaranteed in Python. If you want these in standard form, you'll need to throw in some kind of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you like it really short:

```
class Polynomial(dict):

    def __str__(self):
        return ' + '.join("{}*X^{}".format(self[exp], exp) 
                          for exp in sorted(self, reverse=True))


>>> print Polynomial({4:5,6:7,100:10})
'10*X^100 + 7*X^6 + 5*X^4'
```